# how to show value of previous year metric in google data studio

Tags: looker-studio, date-comparison

I have a table which contain a date dimension (with data for a couple of years) with several metrics. I want to be able to add the metric with the value of last year in the same table with standard metric that shows the value for the selected time period.

[Example - current table in data studio:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfqeI.png)

What i need is to create a `metric1_lastyear` that would display the value of that same metric during the same selected date period but for the previous year.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this, you'll need to blend your Data Source with itself.

First, create a calculated column with the comparison date:

- `Prev_Date` : `DATE(DATETIME_SUB(Date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))`

  You can change the comparison criteria with anything you wish (eg. INTERVAL 1 YEAR, etc). Check [DATETIME_SUB documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9699809) for more information.

After this, create a new data view (Resources > Manage blended data > Add a data view), and add your Data Source twice, as follows:

[image: Blended data source]

Notice how I join the `Prev_Date` with `Date` and that the column `Prev_value` in the second Data Source actually is the `Value` column (I just renamed it to be able to distinguish them).

And there you are:

[image: Table with blended data]

Here is an example report that I used to take snapshots (they're both public and editable, to let you check them):

- [Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/720ab41b-b4e3-40d8-bd5c-f4763eb35946)
- [Data Source used by the report](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nIWzj9aqokKCrxrxgyMHbhdoKF8it_YCMCcbxRp1Z2Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The problem of sharing files publicly is that you can't control the changes. The files were broken, but I just fixed them. If someone notices the files are broken, check the version history or drop me a message.

Comment: Thanks! It works :) But how does this impact the performance of the dashboard? Is there really no other way than merging the same source?

Comment: @MichelK Indeed, this affects performance. Sadly, there is no other way to achieve this. You can, however, move the data for a SQL-based data source (as BigQuery) and bring the data already joined. This way it may benefit from using indexes and possibly will be far more performatic.